# combining conditional knockout and data-binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Hi I was wondering if knockout/data binding can conditionally add classes to an element if a condition meets

right now i have something like

```
    <!-- ko if: ($index() % 2 != 0) -->
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-left" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px; min-height: 60px">
       ...
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: ($index() % 2 == 0) -->
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px; min-height: 60px">
       ...
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

With the ... being a bunch of code.  This is bad because only the one line with the "pull-right" and "pull-left" is different in the 2 code blocks.

Is there a way to just change that one line of code or is this not possible.

Thank you
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the css binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px; min-height: 60px" 
     data-bind="css: {  'pull-left': ($index() % 2 != 0), 
                        'pull-right': ($index() % 2 == 0) }">
       <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) in the docs.

But you best bet might be to actually have a property in your view model that has the class that should be applied (probably in a `ko.computed`), so that you don't have to have that logic messing up your view.

For example, I'm assuming the code above is in a `foreach` binding, and that the items are sub models of some kind. You could do something like:

```
self.myCollection = ko.observableArray();    // your original collection
self.myStyledCollection = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.myCollection().map(function(currItem,idx) {
        return { item : currItem, cssClass : idx % 2 ? "pull-left" : "pull-right" };
    });
});
```

Then you could bind it:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myStyledCollection">
    <div data-bind="css: cssClass">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```